# Is there any record of planetary movement, relative to us?

Tags: space-probe

I was discussing with some friends in addressing every possibilities of geocentric model of universe using experimental evidence rather than eyesight. But then one guy *(in geocentricist-side)* asked,

> Why there's no record of planetary movement *relative to us*, then?

<strike>While there's so many space probes out there giving us information from distant target (orbit/land) of celestial body. It must be somehow send also their position, right?</strike>

Of course I am sure it does. As it is exactly how our scientist knew how far our probes (Parker Solar Probe, Voyager, etc) are. It is also how we could accurately targetting to moving body in space.

But. Is there any trial to sum it all up in one, in timelapse or interactive one like [this](https://eyes.nasa.gov/dsn/dsn.html)? Because I really couldn't find one.

Or I just missing thing?

**Edit:** *(Previously on comment)*

Sorry for the confusion. I was thinking the probe acts like what GPS tracker does (at least for positioning feature). If that's the case. Seeing we have some in Venus, one in Sun, and many more, doesn't it meant we can make visual representation how it actually happened out there?

Don't get me wrong. These guys keep remind me if **it's space**. There's no direction or point of reference. We're just a tiny dots there. How could we be so certain? Nothing could replace experimental evidence, even math. Remember flat earthers detailed theory until we see ourself in space. So does with atom theory, and many more.

I would be so interested if someone had detailed information report regarding position (angles and distance) of our probes through time.

Comment: Are you looking for a record of planets' distance from us, for some sort of rotating-reference-frame graph of the relative orbital speeds, for a table of planetary positions (i.e., a solar system ephemeris), or what?

Comment: @NathanTuggy literally, to "It must somehow also send it's position, right?" the answer is *no, we measure it's position from here* perhaps?

Comment: @talkingpandas your question really isn't very clear to me. Can you leave out the discussion of your friend, and just focus on exactly the question you would like to ask? There is a wide variety of measurements of the positions of planets, but these measurements are complex. Spacecraft are used for many, some don't rely on spacecraft.

Comment: @uhoh Sorry for the confusion. I was thinking the probe acts like what GPS tracker does (at least for positioning feature). If that's the case. Seeing we have some in Venus, one in Sun, and many more, doesn't it means we can make visual representation how it actually happened out there?

Comment: hmm... are you looking for a website that shows where the planets are? Objects in the solar system move very very predictably, so we only measure them once in a while. The rest of the time we just use a computer program to predict where they are moment-to-moment. People do this all the time. If you see a bicycle coming towards you, you might look away for a second, but in your mind you know where it's going to be without looking (usually, at least for 1 or 2 seconds) ;-)

Comment: Exactly. I was thinking the same at first. But these guy keep remind me if **it's space**. There's no direction or point of reference. We're just a tiny dots there. How could we be so certain? Nothing could replace experimental evidence even math. Remember flat earther detailed theory until we see ourself in space. So does with atom theory, and many more.

Comment: @uhoh if I am not mentioning username, will it still send notification to the rest commenter like Nathan? Sorry new user here.

Comment: nope. If you are the author, of the post, then a maximum of one person can be notified. If you are commenting on a different user's post, then the post owner usually gets notified automatically and the `@` will notify a maximum of one more. I'll see if I can find a better explanation and post a link in a minute.

Comment: https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons.cgi - this is a good locator for geocentric nad heliocentric frames of reference.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Actually my question is pointed to the report existence of those probe's _**angles and distance**_ through time. Edited post, sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Space probes generally don't know where they are. A probe's position is determined from Earth, by measuring the angles and distance to the probe.

We can do this [very accurately](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2358/how-did-nasa-determine-the-distance-and-velocity-of-voyager-1/2362#2362): distances are known to ±1 m. Angles are slightly less precise, but still we can send a probe to Pluto and have it arrive within 5 seconds of the planned time. We **know** where these things are beyond any reasonable doubt.

As for there being "no point of reference" - that's incorrect.

1. we don't need an outside reference. When we point a telescope, we know very accurately in which direction it's pointing. We also know the motion of the Earth (again, very accurately), so we have no uncertainty there.
2. far-away stars are a good reference. We [know very accurately where ~1 billion stars are](http://sci.esa.int/gaia/), and we can plot our own motion relative to those stars.

[Here's a nice visualisation](https://eyes.nasa.gov/) of the position of the currently active planetary missions. We need to know exactly where those are or we wouldn't be able to contact them. Every day, a giant dish antenna is pointed at each of them for communications. A [log of those contacts is available](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/17046/is-there-any-publicly-available-logging-or-wayback-machine-for-dsn-now-activi). It gives the azimuth an elevation of each antenna as it was in contact with various deep space missions.

To determine the position of a planet in the solar system, we use the [parallax](https://spaceplace.nasa.gov/review/dr-marc-solar-system/planet-distances.html) method: we observe the planet from 2 points on Earth, and then it's basic geometry to calculate how far away it is. For close objects (inner planets, asteroids) we can do radar ranging as well. 
We've gotten really good at this so we can do things like plot the position and orbit of every one of the *600,000* known asteroids. We can do the same [with the planets](http://astropixels.com/ephemeris/ephemeris.html).

[Youtube visualisation of asteroid discovery](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2k2vkLEE4ko)

The geocentric model of the universe has been comprehensively **disproved** for [several centuries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heliocentrism) now. Not only do we know the geocentric model is not an accurate model, we know it is physically **impossible** for such a solar system to exist. The laws of gravity are well-understood and they conclusively say that all objects in a solar system must orbit around the heaviest object, i.e. the star, and not one of the planets.

> Why there's no record of planetary movement relative to us, then?

That statement is incorrect. There are records, like [JPL's HORIZONS](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/?horizons) database. Records like these are used constantly by astronomers all over the world. They can use this data to aim their telescopes, and invariably find the object where the ephemeris data says it will be. If they didn't, it'd be *major news*.

Planetary movement is so predictable, we don't need to constantly check where the planets are. Databases like Horizons are regularly updated, but the update frequency depends on the object. Planets with an active mission get more frequent updates than minor asteroids.

Comment: Actually my question is pointed to the report existence of those probe's _**angles and distance**_ through time. Edited post, sorry for confusion.

Comment: This part "Every day, a giant dish antenna is pointed at each of them for communications" is what previously thought had raw datasheet everyday to play with. At least for certain range of time. NASA's Eyes aren't showing them. But still best answer and giving me new prespective. :-)

Comment: In case it's there and I missed it, would appreciate if you can add to your answer. Really wanted to see them myself those probe position through time.

Answer (score 4):

There's a lot of [ephermis data available to the public](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons.cgi)...

Here's output for Hubble Telescope's Position relative to the Sun from 12-18-2018 to 12-19-2018.

```
*******************************************************************************
 Revised: Dec 18, 2018           Hubble Space Telescope                     -48
                                 http://hubblesite.org

 BACKGROUND:
  Launched: April 24, 1990 [from space shuttle Discovery (STS-31)]
  Deployed: April 25, 1990

  NOTE: HST ephemeris data can be unreliable during times of the following
        space shuttle servicing missions

         Servicing Mission 1 : 1993 (December 02-14)
         Servicing Mission 2 : 1997 (February 11-21)
         Servicing Mission 3A: 1999 (December 19-28)
         Servicing Mission 3B: 2002 (March    01-12)
         Servicing Mission 4 : 2009 (May      11-25)

 HUBBLE SPACE TELESCOPE:
   Length          : 43.5 ft (13.2 m)   Weight      : 24,500 lb (11,110 kg)
   Maximum Diameter: 14 ft (4.2 m)      Data return : ~120 Gigabytes (GB)/week

 Generic orbit facts:
   Altitude     : 569 km, or 353 miles  Inclination  : 28.5 deg. to equator
   Orbit period : 97 minutes            Orbital speed: 28,000 kph (17500 mph)

 SPACECRAFT TRAJECTORY:
   The trajectory here is a concatenation of publicly released JSpOC two-line
   elements. These can usually only be propagated reliably "days" into the
   future, and are updated frequently to maintain accuracy.
*******************************************************************************


*******************************************************************************
Ephemeris / WWW_USER Tue Dec 18 18:15:21 2018 Pasadena, USA      / Horizons    
*******************************************************************************
Target body name: Hubble Space Telescope (-48)    {source: hst}
Center body name: Sun (10)                        {source: DE431mx}
Center-site name: BODY CENTER
*******************************************************************************
Start time      : A.D. 2018-Dec-18 00:00:00.0000 TDB
Stop  time      : A.D. 2018-Dec-19 00:00:00.0000 TDB
Step-size       : 60 minutes
*******************************************************************************
Center geodetic : 0.00000000,0.00000000,0.0000000 {E-lon(deg),Lat(deg),Alt(km)}
Center cylindric: 0.00000000,0.00000000,0.0000000 {E-lon(deg),Dxy(km),Dz(km)}
Center radii    : 696000.0 x 696000.0 x 696000.0 k{Equator, meridian, pole}    
Keplerian GM    : 2.9591220828559093E-04 au^3/d^2
Output units    : AU-D, deg, Julian Day Number (Tp)                            
Output type     : GEOMETRIC osculating elements
Output format   : 10
Reference frame : ICRF/J2000.0                                                 
Coordinate systm: Ecliptic and Mean Equinox of Reference Epoch                 
*******************************************************************************
JDTDB
   EC    QR   IN
   OM    W    Tp
   N     MA   TA
   A     AD   PR
*******************************************************************************
$$SOE
2458470.500000000 = A.D. 2018-Dec-18 00:00:00.0000 TDB 
 EC= 3.890066300122276E-01 QR= 4.428580425226350E-01 IN= 1.871695552148695E+00
 OM= 8.582954293137250E+01 W = 1.643983560050949E+02 Tp=  2458563.161584661808
 N = 1.597209983917639E+00 MA= 2.119999918526561E+02 TA= 1.955152353146966E+02
 A = 7.248164452774633E-01 AD= 1.006774848032291E+00 PR= 2.253930313639734E+02
2458470.541666667 = A.D. 2018-Dec-18 01:00:00.0000 TDB 
 EC= 5.635862980145503E-01 QR= 9.788749013647081E-01 IN= 2.038757512988334E+00
 OM= 2.657181216132529E+02 W = 1.898442777480302E+02 Tp=  2458478.251881752629
 N = 2.934005005617528E-01 MA= 3.577378190342407E+02 TA= 3.502227004623364E+02
 A = 2.242997634839027E+00 AD= 3.507120368313346E+00 PR= 1.226991771693416E+03
2458470.583333333 = A.D. 2018-Dec-18 02:00:00.0000 TDB 
 EC= 2.768055858567290E-01 QR= 6.208128849542077E-01 IN= 2.217219347460035E+00
 OM= 8.587940693584784E+01 W = 2.253275822489244E+02 Tp=  2458383.090423295274
 N = 1.239211928679328E+00 MA= 1.084222577940879E+02 TA= 1.346172643058766E+02
 A = 8.584315265897772E-01 AD= 1.096050168225347E+00 PR= 2.905072100005242E+02
2458470.625000000 = A.D. 2018-Dec-18 03:00:00.0000 TDB 
 EC= 2.698354287445672E-01 QR= 6.581399830785062E-01 IN= 1.574529200364346E-01
 OM= 2.648070567527593E+02 W = 3.050021454645789E+02 Tp=  2458553.379156670067
 N = 1.151748870572835E+00 MA= 2.646879935200372E+02 TA= 2.360623663950259E+02
 A = 9.013584183452114E-01 AD= 1.144576853611917E+00 PR= 3.125681380707150E+02
2458470.666666667 = A.D. 2018-Dec-18 04:00:00.0000 TDB 
 EC= 5.444349318655588E-01 QR= 9.754286287714100E-01 IN= 1.477904463676805E+00
 OM= 2.658294312883597E+02 W = 1.673075185881981E+02 Tp=  2458460.561185280327
 N = 3.145838698998227E-01 MA= 3.179021441729406E+00 TA= 1.277350169544054E+01
 A = 2.141140085138294E+00 AD= 3.306851541505178E+00 PR= 1.144368909043683E+03
2458470.708333333 = A.D. 2018-Dec-18 05:00:00.0000 TDB 
 EC= 3.979612361579806E-01 QR= 4.282733445410956E-01 IN= 3.417051507508406E+00
 OM= 8.599358407410202E+01 W = 1.902907312707754E+02 Tp=  2458374.435867511667
 N = 1.642703526137086E+00 MA= 1.581471190751705E+02 TA= 1.696684394200481E+02
 A = 7.113717093696620E-01 AD= 9.944700741982284E-01 PR= 2.191509266718147E+02
2458470.750000000 = A.D. 2018-Dec-18 06:00:00.0000 TDB 
 EC= 3.292927048268290E-01 QR= 8.863243603228029E-01 IN= 1.650366995565548E+00
 OM= 2.659011463036582E+02 W = 2.332732956796337E+02 Tp=  2458512.723015938420
 N = 6.488056007382428E-01 MA= 3.327676721792008E+02 TA= 3.068243596819843E+02
 A = 1.321477143161178E+00 AD= 1.756629925999553E+00 PR= 5.548657403548526E+02
2458470.791666667 = A.D. 2018-Dec-18 07:00:00.0000 TDB 
 EC= 3.529207235329300E-01 QR= 9.093596785664838E-01 IN= 2.050901753434128E-01
 OM= 2.654942198012276E+02 W = 1.357189654973226E+02 Tp=  2458435.006706135813
 N = 5.916117221738404E-01 MA= 2.117080212743355E+01 TA= 4.482311550951233E+01
 A = 1.405329627509344E+00 AD= 1.901299576452205E+00 PR= 6.085072125974826E+02
2458470.833333333 = A.D. 2018-Dec-18 08:00:00.0000 TDB 
 EC= 4.107118663383448E-01 QR= 4.144605597122294E-01 IN= 2.795973325823961E+00
 OM= 8.613827813852122E+01 W = 1.710333449998755E+02 Tp=  2458566.980673011858
 N = 1.670978276991784E+00 MA= 1.993398840068245E+02 TA= 1.889101658792065E+02
 A = 7.033241228478487E-01 AD= 9.921876859834678E-01 PR= 2.154426571290311E+02
2458470.875000000 = A.D. 2018-Dec-18 09:00:00.0000 TDB 
 EC= 5.253395968107477E-01 QR= 9.689511496277131E-01 IN= 2.233465816925101E+00
 OM= 2.660600984558036E+02 W = 1.971993527146168E+02 Tp=  2458484.439950083848
 N = 3.379292279399017E-01 MA= 3.554160068910766E+02 TA= 3.428653713704716E+02
 A = 2.041356605938292E+00 AD= 3.113762062248870E+00 PR= 1.065311817491038E+03
2458470.916666667 = A.D. 2018-Dec-18 10:00:00.0000 TDB 
 EC= 2.485022235237878E-01 QR= 7.073369431724252E-01 IN= 1.659681122183811E+00
 OM= 8.623279752588549E+01 W = 2.455775882828054E+02 Tp=  2458390.756088268477
 N = 1.079334631256524E+00 MA= 8.652008832674795E+01 TA= 1.143528930963679E+02
 A = 9.412362422270125E-01 AD= 1.175135541281600E+00 PR= 3.335388206537027E+02
2458470.958333333 = A.D. 2018-Dec-18 11:00:00.0000 TDB 
 EC= 3.037255597845947E-01 QR= 5.771350739841434E-01 IN= 7.130073613670319E-01
 OM= 8.644775341822449E+01 W = 1.405352101129879E+02 Tp=  2458558.473446907476
 N = 1.306046232240753E+00 MA= 2.457012156523637E+02 TA= 2.192275276191876E+02
 A = 8.288902200770089E-01 AD= 1.080645366169874E+00 PR= 2.756410846056777E+02
2458471.000000000 = A.D. 2018-Dec-18 12:00:00.0000 TDB 
 EC= 5.717168572551787E-01 QR= 9.821452923279271E-01 IN= 1.964899843431048E+00
 OM= 2.661866802461665E+02 W = 1.742492948557780E+02 Tp=  2458466.414281854872
 N = 2.838160400476291E-01 MA= 1.301500364698733E+00 TA= 5.814232841030091E+00
 A = 2.293214918601421E+00 AD= 3.604284544874916E+00 PR= 1.268427252876849E+03
2458471.041666667 = A.D. 2018-Dec-18 13:00:00.0000 TDB 
 EC= 3.667041942906853E-01 QR= 4.685285206998341E-01 IN= 3.413345336577104E+00
 OM= 8.632992432352330E+01 W = 1.977451779489694E+02 Tp=  2458377.462883803062
 N = 1.548852076288903E+00 MA= 1.449396921348363E+02 TA= 1.622163748425563E+02
 A = 7.398257125279155E-01 AD= 1.011122904355997E+00 PR= 2.324302013802189E+02
2458471.083333333 = A.D. 2018-Dec-18 14:00:00.0000 TDB 
 EC= 2.791473622546417E-01 QR= 8.358567152924030E-01 IN= 1.233195535343639E+00
 OM= 2.662021780038758E+02 W = 2.520554776061770E+02 Tp=  2458526.457369470038
 N = 7.893617134941028E-01 MA= 3.162898559520107E+02 TA= 2.880804728915811E+02
 A = 1.159538956404110E+00 AD= 1.483221197515817E+00 PR= 4.560646834598338E+02
2458471.125000000 = A.D. 2018-Dec-18 15:00:00.0000 TDB 
 EC= 4.179818344617852E-01 QR= 9.379132212974186E-01 IN= 8.874533039321070E-01
 OM= 2.662508037727385E+02 W = 1.473969703503039E+02 Tp=  2458444.961307437159
 N = 4.817978932365854E-01 MA= 1.260561195601245E+01 TA= 3.272805613338371E+01
 A = 1.611484446417739E+00 AD= 2.285055671538060E+00 PR= 7.472012747536508E+02
2458471.166666667 = A.D. 2018-Dec-18 16:00:00.0000 TDB 
 EC= 4.198362074892005E-01 QR= 4.024542120880462E-01 IN= 3.580571003321839E+00
 OM= 8.646289026416430E+01 W = 1.768511139859748E+02 Tp=  2458572.640550877433
 N = 1.705906760725884E+00 MA= 1.868950148877732E+02 TA= 1.831064249071229E+02
 A = 6.936906737084161E-01 AD= 9.849271353287860E-01 PR= 2.110314633179692E+02
2458471.208333333 = A.D. 2018-Dec-18 17:00:00.0000 TDB 
 EC= 4.720791519388971E-01 QR= 9.531398919726856E-01 IN= 2.270109815228814E+00
 OM= 2.663969634903971E+02 W = 2.056010589318579E+02 Tp=  2458491.507151903119
 N = 4.062770810930514E-01 MA= 3.517530552418927E+02 TA= 3.344664683709711E+02
 A = 1.805459843977155E+00 AD= 2.657779795981624E+00 PR= 8.860947780550478E+02
2458471.250000000 = A.D. 2018-Dec-18 18:00:00.0000 TDB 
 EC= 2.472502800121162E-01 QR= 7.882846198047380E-01 IN= 9.562133617981704E-01
 OM= 8.661724203038496E+01 W = 2.697134227482588E+02 Tp=  2458403.713140975218
 N = 9.197195076082808E-01 MA= 6.211496672778185E+01 TA= 9.017177038366326E+01
 A = 1.047206792474697E+00 AD= 1.306128965144656E+00 PR= 3.914236862673225E+02
2458471.291666667 = A.D. 2018-Dec-18 19:00:00.0000 TDB 
 EC= 3.418546558980847E-01 QR= 5.100612741710432E-01 IN= 1.727702786104948E+00
 OM= 8.664679284630388E+01 W = 1.528163575467588E+02 Tp=  2458561.274996294174
 N = 1.444618814320922E+00 MA= 2.300083890447498E+02 TA= 2.070861718448297E+02
 A = 7.749979221794194E-01 AD= 1.039934570187796E+00 PR= 2.492006863203057E+02
2458471.333333333 = A.D. 2018-Dec-18 20:00:00.0000 TDB 
 EC= 5.788187728011001E-01 QR= 9.839143968072467E-01 IN= 2.356071630717638E+00
 OM= 2.665339722434604E+02 W = 1.809525851632534E+02 Tp=  2458472.039910624735
 N = 2.760397398612049E-01 MA= 3.598049565883123E+02 TA= 3.591034367736571E+02
 A = 2.336083218501570E+00 AD= 3.688252040195893E+00 PR= 1.304160046596953E+03
2458471.375000000 = A.D. 2018-Dec-18 21:00:00.0000 TDB 
 EC= 3.278006892268973E-01 QR= 5.255336841756522E-01 IN= 3.099101963109028E+00
 OM= 8.666986237769650E+01 W = 2.074610187963827E+02 Tp=  2458379.853155388031
 N = 1.425772822120168E+00 MA= 1.304893586777874E+02 TA= 1.524994091413366E+02
 A = 7.818122925047795E-01 AD= 1.038090900833907E+00 PR= 2.524946431961503E+02
2458471.416666667 = A.D. 2018-Dec-18 22:00:00.0000 TDB 
 EC= 2.550762024186538E-01 QR= 7.675475868024005E-01 IN= 5.889697304309631E-01
 OM= 2.663842475549315E+02 W = 2.749948225574341E+02 Tp=  2458540.851092088502
 N = 9.423535716367609E-01 MA= 2.945682212089166E+02 TA= 2.652982698475788E+02
 A = 1.030370608771676E+00 AD= 1.293193630740952E+00 PR= 3.820222163266394E+02
2458471.458333333 = A.D. 2018-Dec-18 23:00:00.0000 TDB 
 EC= 4.781977748198414E-01 QR= 9.581490369337802E-01 IN= 1.542688420108194E+00
 OM= 2.666420250612396E+02 W = 1.568512895714894E+02 Tp=  2458452.955966621637
 N = 3.961077712715380E-01 MA= 7.328931241431910E+00 TA= 2.322214799240389E+01
 A = 1.836230262534751E+00 AD= 2.714311488135722E+00 PR= 9.088435676088124E+02
2458471.500000000 = A.D. 2018-Dec-19 00:00:00.0000 TDB 
 EC= 4.159799470561078E-01 QR= 4.060715225799610E-01 IN= 4.109090203547190E+00
 OM= 8.679420737164742E+01 W = 1.824972358769670E+02 Tp=  2458368.898810586426
 N = 1.699972562968352E+00 MA= 1.744192069313348E+02 TA= 1.774676398499996E+02
 A = 6.953040748054126E-01 AD= 9.845366270308642E-01 PR= 2.117681236992424E+02
$$EOE
*******************************************************************************
Coordinate system description:

  Ecliptic and Mean Equinox of Reference Epoch

    Reference epoch: J2000.0
    XY-plane: plane of the Earth's orbit at the reference epoch
              Note: obliquity of 84381.448 arcseconds wrt ICRF equator (IAU76)
    X-axis  : out along ascending node of instantaneous plane of the Earth's
              orbit and the Earth's mean equator at the reference epoch
    Z-axis  : perpendicular to the xy-plane in the directional (+ or -) sense
              of Earth's north pole at the reference epoch.

  Symbol meaning [1 au= 149597870.700 km, 1 day= 86400.0 s]:

    JDTDB    Julian Day Number, Barycentric Dynamical Time
      EC     Eccentricity, e                                                   
      QR     Periapsis distance, q (au)                                        
      IN     Inclination w.r.t XY-plane, i (degrees)                           
      OM     Longitude of Ascending Node, OMEGA, (degrees)                     
      W      Argument of Perifocus, w (degrees)                                
      Tp     Time of periapsis (Julian Day Number)                             
      N      Mean motion, n (degrees/day)                                      
      MA     Mean anomaly, M (degrees)                                         
      TA     True anomaly, nu (degrees)                                        
      A      Semi-major axis, a (au)                                           
      AD     Apoapsis distance (au)                                            
      PR     Sidereal orbit period (day)                                       

Geometric states/elements have no aberrations applied.

 Computations by ...
     Solar System Dynamics Group, Horizons On-Line Ephemeris System
     4800 Oak Grove Drive, Jet Propulsion Laboratory
     Pasadena, CA  91109   USA
     Information: http://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/
     Connect    : telnet://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov:6775  (via browser)
                  http://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/?horizons
                  telnet ssd.jpl.nasa.gov 6775    (via command-line)
     Author     : Jon.D.Giorgini@jpl.nasa.gov
*******************************************************************************
```

While this is in terms of the Sun, you can get your information in terms of any frame based on any arbitrary observer. I'm sure you could use this data, gathered by NASA, to help verify that we are indeed "orbiting the sun" and having that orbit slightly altered by other, smaller bodies. Here's the exact same data with the body center set as Mars.

```
2458470.500000000 = A.D. 2018-Dec-18 00:00:00.0000 TDB 
 EC= 2.828358766828823E+06 QR= 1.102532516006405E+00 IN= 6.681242179255934E-01
 OM= 6.546255732526792E+01 W = 8.924139302900159E+01 Tp=  2458450.796799411532
 N = 2.300532928263642E+06 MA= 4.532786174621577E+07 TA= 1.562685189055932E+01
 A =-3.898136681776908E-07 AD= 6.684586453809735E+91 PR= 1.157407291666667E+95
2458470.541666667 = A.D. 2018-Dec-18 01:00:00.0000 TDB 
 EC= 3.451627528185236E+06 QR= 8.880375787138227E-01 IN= 5.231874022666452E+00
 OM= 3.574173833171273E+02 W = 1.337543861771784E+02 Tp=  2458433.009774630424
 N = 4.290448856360884E+06 MA= 1.610286632628762E+08 TA= 3.915414820401475E+01
 A =-2.572808997330099E-07 AD= 6.684586453809735E+91 PR= 1.157407291666667E+95
2458470.583333333 = A.D. 2018-Dec-18 02:00:00.0000 TDB 
 EC= 1.250392607765465E+06 QR= 9.288102809335752E-01 IN= 8.214214458891380E-01
 OM= 1.187432903932615E+02 W = 1.582489544484874E+01 Tp=  2458411.458228474483
 N = 8.745660261665307E+05 MA= 5.170880800301877E+07 TA= 3.582045946278900E+01
 A =-7.428155108889629E-07 AD= 6.684586453809735E+91 PR= 1.157407291666667E+95
2458470.625000000 = A.D. 2018-Dec-18 03:00:00.0000 TDB 
 EC= 3.793531833370807E+06 QR= 1.076333503104272E+00 IN= 1.969888528593480E+00
 OM= 9.436048814527449E+00 W = 1.409006284880637E+02 Tp=  2458449.194269890897
 N = 3.704752394593957E+06 MA= 7.939554868886220E+07 TA= 2.006641320668920E+01
 A =-2.837286819013087E-07 AD= 6.684586453809735E+91 PR= 1.157407291666667E+95
2458470.666666667 = A.D. 2018-Dec-18 04:00:00.0000 TDB 
 EC= 2.452829894881510E+06 QR= 7.982426758793240E-01 IN= 5.506413135315369E+00
 OM= 3.571121497069178E+02 W = 1.274370575450030E+02 Tp=  2458422.650413263123
 N = 3.015869289742863E+06 MA= 1.448107440476120E+08 TA= 4.585814055177241E+01
 A =-3.254375702867301E-07 AD= 6.684586453809735E+91 PR= 1.157407291666667E+95
2458470.708333333 = A.D. 2018-Dec-18 05:00:00.0000 TDB 
 EC= 1.624564931704819E+06 QR= 1.067719550883087E+00 IN= 1.713544284803320E+00
 OM= 1.485260643819259E+02 W = 5.872524117496840E-01 Tp=  2458436.056658471003
 N = 1.050832426622336E+06 MA= 3.641310358223425E+07 TA= 2.136542349296744E+01
 A =-6.572345538674008E-07 AD= 6.684586453809735E+91 PR= 1.157407291666667E+95
2458470.750000000 = A.D. 2018-Dec-18 06:00:00.0000 TDB 
 EC= 4.171006506136667E+06 QR= 1.013955247750431E+00 IN= 3.641107153862555E+00
 OM= 5.895193291440325E-01 W = 1.420224386665828E+02 Tp=  2458443.705475046765
 N = 4.671399522335662E+06 MA= 1.263357809491153E+08 TA= 2.786288861375674E+01
 A =-2.430961182522130E-07 AD= 6.684586453809735E+91 PR= 1.157407291666667E+95
2458470.791666667 = A.D. 2018-Dec-18 07:00:00.0000 TDB 
 EC= 1.626171369939449E+06 QR= 7.736390813408517E-01 IN= 3.846628155274235E+00
 OM= 6.564515412071506E-02 W = 1.228414977740317E+02 Tp=  2458411.004897375591
 N = 1.706300479242473E+06 MA= 1.020141930937214E+08 TA= 4.759361094698946E+01
 A =-4.757429452915557E-07 AD= 6.684586453809735E+91 PR= 1.157407291666667E+95
2458470.833333333 = A.D. 2018-Dec-18 08:00:00.0000 TDB 
 EC= 2.523243666156683E+06 QR= 1.105670782159703E+00 IN= 9.126792750676497E-01
 OM= 1.263049886549134E+02 W = 2.872203596694196E+01 Tp=  2458450.020750527270
 N = 1.930251184519402E+06 MA= 4.017351261442514E+07 TA= 1.552958362199773E+01
 A =-4.381943904919076E-07 AD= 6.684586453809735E+91 PR= 1.157407291666667E+95
2458470.875000000 = A.D. 2018-Dec-18 09:00:00.0000 TDB 
 EC= 3.737762307637203E+06 QR= 9.224190051441182E-01 IN= 5.136098754582626E+00
 OM= 3.576700504445394E+02 W = 1.363489854571452E+02 Tp=  2458436.140141763259
 N = 4.567084327282084E+06 MA= 1.586370266629348E+08 TA= 3.652912476739448E+01
 A =-2.467838176984120E-07 AD= 6.684586453809735E+91 PR= 1.157407291666667E+95
2458470.916666667 = A.D. 2018-Dec-18 10:00:00.0000 TDB 
 EC= 1.265996011749275E+06 QR= 8.789464378551831E-01 IN= 7.229092855330699E-01
 OM= 5.210368416242102E+01 W = 7.845261212746220E+01 Tp=  2458407.923894887790
 N = 9.678731101700607E+05 MA= 6.096900993958652E+07 TA= 4.004817014907447E+01
 A =-6.942732235893315E-07 AD= 6.684586453809735E+91 PR= 1.157407291666667E+95
2458470.958333333 = A.D. 2018-Dec-18 11:00:00.0000 TDB 
 EC= 3.565277043083449E+06 QR= 1.091088435800096E+00 IN= 1.257809242004546E+00
 OM= 2.086416870922220E+01 W = 1.315547359613442E+02 Tp=  2458450.638499598484
 N = 3.307225899490910E+06 MA= 6.720228040122731E+07 TA= 1.821012639289374E+01
 A =-3.060319657202370E-07 AD= 6.684586453809735E+91 PR= 1.157407291666667E+95
2458471.000000000 = A.D. 2018-Dec-18 12:00:00.0000 TDB 
 EC= 2.783951751106697E+06 QR= 8.259924183660451E-01 IN= 5.946834898695882E+00
 OM= 3.567465849142453E+02 W = 1.298461145593930E+02 Tp=  2458426.486800262239
 N = 3.464513667191972E+06 MA= 1.542165888623374E+08 TA= 4.403361720170125E+01
 A =-2.966979275900232E-07 AD= 6.684586453809735E+91 PR= 1.157407291666667E+95
2458471.041666667 = A.D. 2018-Dec-18 13:00:00.0000 TDB 
 EC= 1.462722232935106E+06 QR= 1.039570530975310E+00 IN= 1.922208804882674E+00
 OM= 1.515113716663136E+02 W = 3.539560103558315E+02 Tp=  2458428.776509807911
 N = 9.344917180338012E+05 MA= 3.949643904596099E+07 TA= 2.523331249277140E+01
 A =-7.107099477111583E-07 AD= 6.684586453809735E+91 PR= 1.157407291666667E+95
2458471.083333333 = A.D. 2018-Dec-18 14:00:00.0000 TDB 
 EC= 4.170852376178063E+06 QR= 1.039805510655733E+00 IN= 3.067075234966004E+00
 OM= 2.558910086001370E+00 W = 1.428912020856087E+02 Tp=  2458446.026683209464
 N = 4.498036215618622E+06 MA= 1.127057196989167E+08 TA= 2.524983351239686E+01
 A =-2.493029400650938E-07 AD= 6.684586453809735E+91 PR= 1.157407291666667E+95
2458471.125000000 = A.D. 2018-Dec-18 15:00:00.0000 TDB 
 EC= 1.853277397387270E+06 QR= 7.737038607544687E-01 IN= 5.010484898179223E+00
 OM= 3.579451881753719E+02 W = 1.250566353011800E+02 Tp=  2458414.878213554621
 N = 2.075688572378209E+06 MA= 1.167508118580787E+08 TA= 4.771348707914111E+01
 A =-4.174789372190939E-07 AD= 6.684586453809735E+91 PR= 1.157407291666667E+95
2458471.166666667 = A.D. 2018-Dec-18 16:00:00.0000 TDB 
 EC= 2.230092469257339E+06 QR= 1.104306625791051E+00 IN= 1.576535779783559E+00
 OM= 1.473033394068552E+02 W = 7.224788222368214E+00 Tp=  2458447.982451139949
 N = 1.606806374059324E+06 MA= 3.725254528535004E+07 TA= 1.625396597421208E+01
 A =-4.951844536488029E-07 AD= 6.684586453809735E+91 PR= 1.157407291666667E+95
2458471.208333333 = A.D. 2018-Dec-18 17:00:00.0000 TDB 
 EC= 3.975721750814016E+06 QR= 9.559426975589589E-01 IN= 4.849665851912922E+00
 OM= 3.582074739034499E+02 W = 1.387430109163686E+02 Tp=  2458439.071172898170
 N = 4.748867660477191E+06 MA= 1.526151218902406E+08 TA= 3.382113260135957E+01
 A =-2.404451312037526E-07 AD= 6.684586453809735E+91 PR= 1.157407291666667E+95
2458471.250000000 = A.D. 2018-Dec-18 18:00:00.0000 TDB 
 EC= 1.333118614857236E+06 QR= 8.361229515097572E-01 IN= 1.716852870115054E+00
 OM= 1.222224761394738E+01 W = 1.151883208246531E+02 Tp=  2458407.154352869373
 N = 1.127227385188323E+06 MA= 7.225036871702081E+07 TA= 4.340774408659066E+01
 A =-6.271936865820332E-07 AD= 6.684586453809735E+91 PR= 1.157407291666667E+95
2458471.291666667 = A.D. 2018-Dec-18 19:00:00.0000 TDB 
 EC= 3.292809379190900E+06 QR= 1.102316493603252E+00 IN= 6.636541300577026E-01
 OM= 6.106163750086713E+01 W = 9.301449152474392E+01 Tp=  2458451.612635103986
 N = 2.890708350323432E+06 MA= 5.688634086353931E+07 TA= 1.677921594820431E+01
 A =-3.347648471041947E-07 AD= 6.684586453809735E+91 PR= 1.157407291666667E+95
2458471.333333333 = A.D. 2018-Dec-18 20:00:00.0000 TDB 
 EC= 3.122343635291321E+06 QR= 8.575462631751450E-01 IN= 6.142098951269197E+00
 OM= 3.566879084938599E+02 W = 1.322856170008066E+02 Tp=  2458430.108279428445
 N = 3.889990573961930E+06 MA= 1.603650711015595E+08 TA= 4.187337207405460E+01
 A =-2.746483532852679E-07 AD= 6.684586453809735E+91 PR= 1.157407291666667E+95
2458471.375000000 = A.D. 2018-Dec-18 21:00:00.0000 TDB 
 EC= 1.353872518158523E+06 QR= 1.000305334267380E+00 IN= 1.748941053259557E+00
 OM= 1.500516073164173E+02 W = 3.511369919054122E+02 Tp=  2458421.123353189323
 N = 8.816198277095630E+05 MA= 4.430284820335750E+07 TA= 2.973181006831858E+01
 A =-7.388480523085022E-07 AD= 6.684586453809735E+91 PR= 1.157407291666667E+95
2458471.416666667 = A.D. 2018-Dec-18 22:00:00.0000 TDB 
 EC= 4.091845159263547E+06 QR= 1.062279461920989E+00 IN= 2.363426330221494E+00
 OM= 6.164468731235916E+00 W = 1.419546359128071E+02 Tp=  2458448.126545640640
 N = 4.232865785312530E+06 MA= 9.858395642689350E+07 TA= 2.280668935729997E+01
 A =-2.596089735030812E-07 AD= 6.684586453809735E+91 PR= 1.157407291666667E+95
2458471.458333333 = A.D. 2018-Dec-18 23:00:00.0000 TDB 
 EC= 2.124325065230607E+06 QR= 7.850424156470320E-01 IN= 5.980517149847962E+00
 OM= 3.569008051140928E+02 W = 1.269584387458753E+02 Tp=  2458418.956219899468
 N = 2.492329846582534E+06 MA= 1.308525843207910E+08 TA= 4.707205124719028E+01
 A =-3.695492738118614E-07 AD= 6.684586453809735E+91 PR= 1.157407291666667E+95
2458471.500000000 = A.D. 2018-Dec-19 00:00:00.0000 TDB 
 EC= 1.963479422984855E+06 QR= 1.097108233674135E+00 IN= 2.206758076682791E+00
 OM= 1.547053634182576E+02 W = 3.583881423314380E+02 Tp=  2458444.372835949995
 N = 1.340537712393785E+06 MA= 3.636498643910860E+07 TA= 1.791328582093413E+01
 A =-5.587574688018856E-07 AD= 6.684586453809735E+91 PR= 1.157407291666667E+95
```

You can plot these two data-sets and get wildly different graphs based on the observer, but one will make much more sense (in terms of physics) than the other. If you look at the Mars plot and try to say "Mars is the only thing that is effecting Hubble Space Telescope!" Physics is going to disagree strongly.

While this isn't a very in-depth answer, I feel I can at least point you in the right direction and get you data to play with yourself.

Comment: Looks like exactly what @Hobbes said; that we're really understand the universe for giving such detail. Even seems it is predicted value instead of .pdf showing actual number, but really interesting to start playing around with. Thanks!